Find & replace multiline text block without eol
col1              col2           col3
----------------- -------------- ----
hello_world       345            1234

The goal is to remove multiline intext pattern:
-
 

to get this:
col1        col2 col3
----------- ---- ----
hello_world 345  1234

the pattern here is screenshot:

How to achieve this kind of vertical pattern without eol or other end of line \r\n or else?

So you are looking to delete those extra -'s?  Are there more rows than one - so more rows under hello_world for example that need to be considered?  And these are in a plaintext file or ...?  I assume col2 can be any length?

@Mark this is ascii table (came from plain text output ssms sql query output) and I'd like to internally trim those extra spaces which are three lines tall having - between spaces above and below; there can be more rows certainly but even 3rows height scenario will be fine for now;
